# Static member initialization not working with GCC even with C++11 enabled

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I am using GCC 4.8.2:

```
$ g++ --version                          
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And I have this class definition:

```
#pragma once

#include "SpreadsheetCell.h"

class Spreadsheet 
{
    public:
        Spreadsheet(int inWidth, int inHeight);
        Spreadsheet(const Spreadsheet& src);
        ~Spreadsheet();

        int getId() const;
        int getWidth() const;
        int getHeight() const;
        void setCellAt(int x, int y, const SpreadsheetCell& cell);
        SpreadsheetCell getCellAt(int x, int y) const;

        Spreadsheet& operator=(const Spreadsheet& rhs);
    private:
        bool inRange(int val, int upper) const;
        void copyFrom(const Spreadsheet& src);
        void freeMemory();

        int mWidth, mHeight, mId;
        SpreadsheetCell** mCells;

        static int sCounter = 0;
};
```

When I try to compile it, I get:

```
$ make SpreadsheetTest && SpreadsheetTest
g++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 -c Spreadsheet.cpp
In file included from Spreadsheet.cpp:3:0:
Spreadsheet.h:27:31: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘Spreadsheet::sCounter’
         static int sCounter = 0;
                               ^
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'Spreadsheet.o' failed
make: *** [Spreadsheet.o] Error 1
```

**The strange thing is that if I remove the `static` modifier from `sCounter` declaration, it compiles normally.**

What is going on?

### Edit:

It seems like this feature is available since GCC 4.7:
http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

### Edit 2:

I'm trying to find the official reference, but I took this piece of code from the book "Professional C++" - 2nd edition, from Gregoire, Solter & Kleper (Chapter 7, page 181, subsection "static Data Members") and it is supposed to work.

> With C++11, that's all you need to do. If you are using C++ pior to C++11, it is a little bit clumsier [...]

And then it suggests me to do the traditional way.

Are the authors wrong?

Comment: Re: your edit.  Which feature (ie. which proposal number) supports your claim that this should work?

Comment: I think you confused something about C++11 - It does not allow initialization of non-const static members inside the class definition. static members still have to be initialised out side of the class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error message again:

> ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of **non-const** static member ‘Spreadsheet::sCounter’
>            static int sCounter = 0;

If you want to initialize a `static` member in class definition, it needs to be `const`, that's all there is to it.

Normal class members are initialized when an object of that class is constructed. You can think of in-class initializers as a syntactic sugar for member initializer lists (or think of them as similar to default function arguments). You can still override it and initialize them with a different expression the old way (in a constructor).

Static members are different. They don't belong to any class instance and as such need to have memory allocated for them and be initialized separately. As they have static storage duration, that's somewhere at the programs startup.

Constant static members are an exception. As they can't be written to, the standard allows 
you to initialize them in class declaration and they're basically treated as a value, not an object. That is, until you do something with them that requires them to be stored somewhere, for example take their address. This hasn't changed in C++11.

Standardese quotes, from n3337 draft, chapter 9.4.2 (emphasis mine):

> 2 The declaration of a static data member in its class deﬁnition is not a deﬁnition and may be of an incomplete
>   type other than cv-qualiﬁed void. **The deﬁnition for a static data member shall appear in a namespace
>   cope enclosing the member’s class deﬁnition.** In the deﬁnition at namespace scope, the name of the static
>   data member shall be qualiﬁed by its class name using the :: operator. The initializer expression in the
>   deﬁnition of a static data member is in the scope of its class (3.3.7). [...]

and

> 3 **If a non-volatile const static data member is of integral or enumeration type, its declaration in the class
>   deﬁnition can specify a brace-or-equal-initializer** in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment
>   expression is a constant expression (5.19). A static data member of literal type can be declared in the
>   class deﬁnition with the constexpr speciﬁer; if so, its declaration shall specify a brace-or-equal-initializer
>   in which every initializer-clause that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. [Note: In both
>   these cases, the member may appear in constant expressions. —end note ] **The member shall still be deﬁned
>   in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2)** in the program and the namespace scope deﬁnition shall not
>   contain an initializer.

Comment: But why do I can initialize a non-const and non-static member, but not a non-const static member?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos Updated the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: It do makes sense, I'm being a little bit stubborn because of the book I pointed out, but maybe the authors got it wrong...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I added some normative qutoes to prove that those guys are indeed wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the static definition out of the class declaration:

```
class Spreadsheet 
{
   ...
   static int sCounter;
};

int Spreadsheet::sCounter = 0;
```

Comment: Yeah, I know this, but in C++11 things have changed. Note that if I remove the `static` modifier, it compiles normally...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: In case of static you need `const`, by the way it's how C++11 works.

Comment: I'm trying to find the official reference, but I took this piece of code from the book "Professional C++", from Gregoire, Solter & Kleper and it is supposed to work.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: You should combine some quotes to deduce this result. I think in the case standard just says what is possible (counter-intuitive) -- (e.g. Part §9.5/3 says what is possible).

Comment: Updated my answer indicating from where I took the code. Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

- C++98 allows in-class initializers for static `const` members of integral or enum types.
- C++11 additionally allows in-class initializers for non-static members.

Your code does not fall into either category. It was never supposed to compile in C++98 and it is not supposed to compile in C++11. In C++ you are not allowed to provide in-class initializers for non-const static members.

Note also that the original C++98 feature has not been extended to non-integral non-enum types

```
struct S {
  static const double d = 5; // still an error even in C++11
};
```

BTW, the semantics of and the rationale behind in-class initializers for static const and non-static class data members is completely different. Despite being similar syntactically, these are actually two different features, not an extension of the former onto the latter.

- In-class initializers for static const data members exist to facilitate "early" Integral Constant Expressions, i.e. they turn a static constant onto an ICE at the point of class definition (as opposed to the later point of static member definition).
- In-class initializers for non-static data member facilitate implicit initialization of class members in constructors. In other words, what in C++11 looks like in-class initializers for non-static data members do not really initialize anything yet. (There's nothing to initialize at that point.) All these in-class initializers do is supply the compiler with information that is used later for generating class constructors. These constructors will do they job even later, when you actually begin defining objects of that class type.

Comment: No definition was required, in C++03, for static const integral type class data members if the reference is not taken.

Was this the same for C++98 as well ?

I have sources that it in-class initialization is allowed for integral types in C++98 but not for what I am asking